# Access an array from a parent class

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array defined in the parent class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Original extends PrintWriter {

   protected char alphabet[] = {'z','a','e','t','h','l'};
}
```

In my child class, under the class definition, I am just doing:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Child1 extends Original{

alphabet[0]='e';
alphabet[1]='b';
}
```

and so on....
but it is not letting me do this.

Comment: It should not if you do it in correct way. Can you show us the full code?

Comment: `"but it is not letting me do this."` -- what is telling you? How? If you see error codes, please show them here. Also, care must be taken when trying to use a parent's fields. Sometimes inheritance is not the way to solve this.

Comment: Show us the code for this and tell us the compiler error. The answer is almost certainly contextual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines are syntactically wrong.

While you are accessing them you should write them in any method or constructor.

*If you write them outside of constructor of method then compiler considered them as declaratiions*

```
import java.io.*;
public class Child1 extends Original{

alphabet[0]='e';
alphabet[1]='b';
}
```

Should be

```
 protected Child(){
       alphabet[0]='e';
       alphabet[1]='b';
    }
```

or  in any methods of `Child` class.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a class you can only have code blocks, methods or variable declarations. You must change your code as the other answers suggested. For instance:

```
public class Parent {
    protected char alphabet[] = {'a', 'b', 'd'};
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(){
        alphabet[2] = 'c';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain me why the down votes? Not for my reputation, but for my understanding.

Comment: Probably because it was posted when we did not know what the OP's problem was. Simply presenting compilable code is not really an answer because it doesn't provide an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right and that is something that I will think next time.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with inheritance. Your problem is that you're trying to call methods naked out in the class and outside of any constructor or method where this is allowed. Put that code in a constructor or method where it belongs.

i.e., change this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Child1 extends Original{

  // this can't go here!
  alphabet[0]='e';
  alphabet[1]='b';
}
```

to this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Child1 extends Original{

 public Child1() {
   alphabet[0]='e';
   alphabet[1]='b';
 }
}
```

But I reiterate my comment, when you run into similar problems in the future and need our help, please show enough code so that we can understand the problem, and always, **please show your complete error message**, something you've still not done.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Child1 extends Original{
   public void test(){

     alphabet[0]='e';
     alphabet[1]='b';
  }
}
```

Operations have to be inside method or constructor

Comment: *"Operations have to be inside method or constructor"* Which your `test` is compilable for neither.

Comment: test is a method which does not return anything. Why java.io?

Comment: I just copy a code from the question )